# Ajax-Http-Request is pending even if chrome got no internet connection

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios, google-chrome-devtools, workbox

I am setting up a new VueJS-Project and implemented a workbox-backgroundSync in my progressive web application. To test this workbox plugin i need to disconnect my device (chrome) from the internet and fire a POST-request. Under chrome this request got a state of pending for couple of minutes, even with no internet connection. So my application is waiting to the request response.

My POST-request:

```
 axios
      .post('/createrecipe', recipe)
      .then(response => {
              commit('createRecipes', recipes);
              commit('setSnackbar', { text: "Recipe was created. ( " + response.data.status + response.status + " )", color:'success', snack:true });
                    console.log("Response from Server for create Recipe: ", response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    commit('setSnackbar', { text: "Your Post will be stored and send by Internet-Connection", color: 'warning', snack: true });
                    console.log(error)
                });
```

My ServiceWorker:

```
const matchCb = ({url, event}) => {
    return (url.pathname === '/api/createrecipe');
};

const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('createdRecipes-post-storage-offline', {
    maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60, // Retry for max of 24 Hours
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    matchCb,
    workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
        plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```

I interrupted the network in Chrome-devtool under the network tab and the background process went through successfully. But this is not the best solution for the users, because they dont know how to control the devtool.

I expect that the request will be canceled, while chrome has no internet connection.

Here is a screenshot of the request in a state of pending instead of failed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWUxK.png)

Side Note: My web application runs under localhost.

Comment: Looks you don't POST. i think some characters are settled false.
share some code , then people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution but my mate [Ilja KO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4594902/ilja-ko) found a workaround. I just set a timeout with the instance of axios to abort the requests, even if chrome got a internet-connection or not.

```
axios.defaults.timeout = 5000;
```